# Sending Property Value to Wix Extension Method

Tags: wix, properties, wix-extension

I have a wix property

```
<Property Id="VAR1" Value="aValue" />
```

And i want to send this value into my Extension method

```
<Property Id="TEST" Value="$(extension.GetResult(VAR1)"  />
```

I want to send the value aValue into the GetResult method, but cant seem to find
the correct syntax to convert VAR1 to 'aValue'

The extension is a preprocessor extension and the Property VAR1 will get set via the user interface...

Comment: I dont think you can pass a value from user to pre processor

Comment: yes i think you are right, i am using custom actions instead now which seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties are only available at runtime, other than by parsing source itself.

Comment: Yes, I have been reading up on it and you are correct. I am now using Custom Actions to handle user property data to perform my "custom actions" :-).